# Moving 3D shape with GLUT?

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I'm working on a snake game.

This is my snake:

```
void snake()
{
 glPushMatrix();
 glColor3f(1,1,1);
 glTranslatef(t,cy,cz);
 glutSolidCube(0.9);
 glPopMatrix();
}
```

I am trying to get the snake continue on moving in a direction when i press a key.
I attempt this:

```
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
{   

    if(key=='z'){cz-=1;}
    if(key=='s'){cz+=1;}

    if(key=='q'){cx-=1;}
    if(key=='d'){cx+=1;}

    if(key=='a'){cy-=1;}
    if(key=='w'){cy+=1;}

    glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

it's working fine but i want it to keep moving until i change the key.

I am unsure on how to go about this.

Any help on the matter?

Comment: Hint: you want to somehow store these `c{x,y,z}{+,-}=1` to represent your snake's speed, updating them from the key events and using their value afterwards. What can you use to this end?

Comment: This article will help you: http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/rotation.html You need to create a transformation matrix

Comment: @Asesh I'm pretty sure OP has already achieved the display, but needs help about data storage.

Comment: @Quentin i really didnt get ur point, Could you please explain more.

Comment: @Asesh yep i already achieved the display.

Comment: @ccr0x you can store the speed as three components between -1 and 1, one for each dimension, stored in 3 `int` variables.

Comment: @Quentin well my issue is not with the speed, i dont want the snake to be moving with 1 each time i call the keyboard function.

Comment: Where is your `glutTimerFunc()` or `glutIdleFunc()` callback for animation/physics updates?  Edit in a [mcve].